# margin overlapping in Chrome

Tags: html, css, margin

I am working on a site and i have some css issue in it. its look good of FF but little weired on Chrome. please kindly help me how can i solve this issue.

http://thesunkissedgirls.com.au/

this is the main page and if you scroll down the page you see 3 paragarphs, and they look ok in ff but when you check in chorme the are mixing header line with first paragraph.

please kindly help me out to fix

```
<div style="color: white;font-size: 14px;margin: 0 0 30px 0;padding: 0;position: absolute;text-align: left;top: 780px;width: 960px; display:block;">
     Promotional Models | Photographic Models | Bikini Models | Lingerie Models | Model Competitions| Sporting Events | Dancer’s | Cheerleaders | Card Girls | Grid Girls |Poker Nights | Promo Girls | Karaoke + more
</div>
```

and the paragraph css is

```
#xtra-paragraph {
    color: #DBDBDB;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    display: block;
}

#xtra-paragraph p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: It's broken in FF too FYI - and heads up this isn't quite SFW ;)

Comment: do you put div around the paragraph?

Comment: @Alien Those girls are from where I live, the Sunshine Coast :)

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely positioning it there, so the browser can't allocate the space for it had it been statically positioned.

You need to put more room there...

```
#xtra-paragraph {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

...or put the HTML where it should belogically and keep it positioned as `static` by default.

Comment: well i am fixing wordpress theme, and it is designed very messy. so please help me how to get rid of this

Comment: @Muzammil The way you are doing it is *hacky*. **But**, the answer I gave does work (so long as that white text's height is consistent).

Answer (score 0):

It's broken in FF too. The div with all the inline CSS, change `top:780px;` to `top:760px;`

Answer (score 0):

In your div style, change "top: 780px;" to "top: 770px;" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To div class `.social` remove `float:left`,

For the div containing

> Promotional Models | Photographic Models | Bikini Models | Lingerie
>   Models | Model Competitions| Sporting Events | Dancer’s | Cheerleaders
>   | Card Girls | Grid Girls |Poker Nights | Promo Girls | Karaoke + more

add `float:left`.

Lastly, increase `margin-top` for `#xtra-paragraph`

**Update:**

Using Yslow! I tested your site's speed. Your overall performance score 65. That is very slow. I suggest that you optimize your site, the theme code is very sloppy.

Comment: my mistake I must have meant another div. It seems fine now tho